# Log-likelihood for multinominal normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Given $n$ jointly-normal random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, with 
$$\mu_i=\mu\forall i \in\mathbb{N}^+$$
$$\sigma_i=\sigma\forall i$$
$$\rho_{i,j}=\rho\forall i,j \mbox{ with } i\neq j$$
what is their log-likelihood function?

My idea is the following:
Be $\mathbf{x}=(X_1,X_2, \dots,X_n)^T$ the vector of observed values and $\mu=(\mu, \dots,\mu)^T$ a $n\times1$-Vektor. Then the $n\times n$ covariance matrix is given by $\Sigma$ with all diagonal elements being $\sigma^2$ and all other entries $\rho\sigma^2$.

The log-likelihood is given by:
$$ L(\mu, \sigma, \rho) =\log [ exp(\frac{-1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)^T)\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu))]$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $\rho_i$? If you mean by that a correlation parameter, then it should have a double index (the correlation is really a measure of dependence between two variables).

Comment: @nullUser Please see my edit.

Comment: @Learner My mistake, I edited the question. It should have a double index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\boldsymbol{x}= \left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1\\
  \vdots\\
  x_n
\end{array}\right)$ (here, this means one observation of the $n$-dimensional
multivariate normally distributed vector), then the log-likelihood is
proportional to
$$ - \frac{1}{2} \log ( \left| \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \right|) -
   \frac{1}{2} \left(
   \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu} \right)^T
   \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{- 1} \left(
   \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu} \right) $$
$\left| \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \right|$ is the determinant of
$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ and including it is essential.

Please note that in the typical setup, you would have say $N$ vectors
$\boldsymbol{x}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{x}_N$.